# iPhone - Memory Leak - NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl & UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks

Please help! Have been staring at this for 12 hours; and have looked online and can't find solution.

In my application, I use 2 UIView controls in separate pages/controllers:

- UIImageView (retrieve data via
  NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl)
- UIWebView

Just to isolate my code, and make it easier to explain, I created a new view based project called "MyTestApplication"

1 - I added a simple NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl in the delegate function.

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
  [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif"]];
```

(Nothing to release here since it's all using convenience functions)

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20081110-j5tn5n7ixph95ys4rpchibaw5p.preview.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20081110-j5tn5n7ixph95ys4rpchibaw5p.preview.jpg)

[View Image](http://img.skitch.com/20081110-j5tn5n7ixph95ys4rpchibaw5p.jpg)

2 - Run it to verify no leaks (as expected)

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20081110-fy2qrkgy47hm4fe2f1aakd4muw.preview.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20081110-fy2qrkgy47hm4fe2f1aakd4muw.preview.jpg)

[View Image](http://img.skitch.com/20081110-fy2qrkgy47hm4fe2f1aakd4muw.jpg)

3 - Open the ViewController.xib and simply add a UIWebView from the library (no need to wire it up)

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20081110-d63c3yh1a1kqiciy73q8uyd68j.preview.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20081110-d63c3yh1a1kqiciy73q8uyd68j.preview.jpg)

[View Image](http://img.skitch.com/20081110-d63c3yh1a1kqiciy73q8uyd68j.jpg)

4 - Run it to verify there are leaks! (why???)

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20081110-qtxcfwntbcc3csabda3r6nfjg6.preview.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20081110-qtxcfwntbcc3csabda3r6nfjg6.preview.jpg)

[View Image](http://img.skitch.com/20081110-qtxcfwntbcc3csabda3r6nfjg6.jpg)

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Why would NSData cause memory leak if I'm using UIWebView? I just don't get it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I was also having trouble with leaks from NSData's `dataWithContentsOfURL:` in the iPhone simulator.  I found that when I used the other convenience method  (`dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:`) I would not get the memory leak.

My code looked something like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url
                                     options:0
                                       error:&error];
```

[Link to documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:)

Comment: Saw this same leak in OS 3.1.2 (on sim and 3GS).  Your suggestion fixed it!  Weird that NSDataReadingOptions is apparently not in the iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what's happening:

When ViewController.xib is loaded, an instance of UIWebView is allocated and initialized. Since you're not wiring it up anywhere, it's not getting released. I think you need to wire it up and release it in your backing View Controller's dealloc function. I remember having to manually release every object I created in a xib file.

Comment: not true. things in the xib are retained by the view controller's `initWithNib` and are released when the view controller is deallocated. and in any case, if this were true, it would also show the web view and NSData as leaked, which is not the case

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Leaks on the Simulator? If so, caveat coder. The Simulator will leak memory where the iPhone hardware won't. No simulator is ever a perfect match for the exact behavior of your code on the device.

I would test on the device as well. I just did the same thing on a similar issue with UITableViewController which was leaking in the Sim but not on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

`[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error]` did not help me on iOS8.

But following works correctly:

```objectivec
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL];
NSData* imageData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:request];
```

Production code would need also response and error parameters.