# Where has this memory gone?

Tags: ios, memory, tvos, apple-tv

I'm doing development on AppleTV, and I have a thread to download posters.

In my first version, I use [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:...] to do this, and the system memory get exhausted soon, though there's no memory leak.

Then I turn to ASIHTTPRequest recommended by coneybeare in this post [memory-leak-problem-using-nsdata-in-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250050/memory-leak-problem-using-nsdata-in-iphone)

Things get better, but still out of memory.

The weird thing is that the resident memory of my process is very low and stable, but the available memory of the system go less and less.

Here is output of vm_stat:

```
Apple TV:/var/log root# vm_stat
Mach Virtual Memory Statistics: (page size of 4096 bytes)
Pages free:                     1012.
Pages active:                  22735.
Pages inactive:                11178.
Pages wired down:              16069.
"Translation faults":         600863.
Pages copy-on-write:           21787.
Pages zero filled:            559108.
Pages reactivated:              2922.
Pageins:                       15073.
Pageouts:                         11.
Object cache: 4 hits of 7781 lookups (0% hit rate)

Apple TV:/var/log root# vm_stat
Mach Virtual Memory Statistics: (page size of 4096 bytes)
Pages free:                      973.
Pages active:                   4568.
Pages inactive:                11067.
Pages wired down:              16076.
"Translation faults":         602533.
Pages copy-on-write:           21881.
Pages zero filled:            559767.
Pages reactivated:              3529.
Pageins:                       15087.
Pageouts:                         11.
Object cache: 4 hits of 7784 lookups (0% hit rate)
```

These two outputs are got subsequently in a very short time period.
Please pay attention to "Pages active:", about 18k pages are gone. 
Where have them gone?

PS. I also found similar problem in CoreGraphics and VideoToolBox, that is, it seems system will occupy a lot of memory and don't release them. Are there caches for CoreAnimation and VideoToolBox? If yes, how can I clear these caches?

Some updates: 
1) It seems to be related with BRMarqueeTextControl, -a text control which is based on CoreAnimation I think.

2)Using BRMarqueeTextControl alone will not cause memory problem, and the poster downloading job alone will neither.

3)When these two come together, memory get exhausted soon.

Comment: vm_stat is not the best way to determine usage by your program. What does Instruments say you're using? Look especially at the analysis provided by Heapshot: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/

Comment: @RobNapier Does Instruments work with the AppleTV? If so, can you point me at instructions on setting it up?

Comment: When checking with Instruments, the memory usage is very stable. However, there's a difference between the version on simulator and the version on AppleTV hardware, -the former is based on UIKit while the later is based on BackRow. The resident memory of my process and the system available memory mentioned in my post are retrieved using host_statistics(...) and task_info(...) at runtime in my code.

Comment: Some updates: it seems to be related with BRMarqueeTextControl, -a text control which is based on CoreAnimation I think. Using BRMarqueeTextControl alone will not cause memory problem, and the poster downloading job alone will neither. When these two come together, memory get exhausted soon.

Comment: I am facing the same issue on iOS 5. Heapshots are not helping, and Allocations doesn't indicate any noticeable memory growth. VM tracker doesn't show any spikes or increases either. However, the Activity Monitor shows that the free memory drops down to zero fairly fast at times. The activity monitor's free memory is also consistent with what `vm_stat` tells me.