# Memory leak while using performSelectorInBackground

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, background-process, performselector

I am new to iOS development. I am facing problems while running a background thread. In my code resetUi is running on main UI thread, Now I am starting a background thread to fetch an image data and update my image. Everything works fine, but memory is leaking when call is made to performSelectorInBackground.

Please let me know where I am doing wrong. Also please suggest if there is a better way to update my image while fetching from an URL(dataWithContentsOfURL).

[Update]

Instrument is displaying 2 separate leaks one at perfromSelectorInBackground and other at UIImage imageWithData. I guess something is going terribly wrong with imageupdate(imageWithData)

```
-(void)updateData{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];     

    profileName.text = oAuthTwitter.screen_name;

    if(profilePic.image == nil){
        NSString *urlString = @"https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/";
        urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingFormat:oAuthTwitter.screen_name];   
        urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingFormat:@"?size=bigger"];            
        profilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];          
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        [activityIndicator release];
    }   
    [pool drain];   

}   

- (void)resetUi{

    if (oAuthTwitter.oauth_token_authorized) {
        profilePic.hidden = NO;
        profileName.hidden = NO;

        NSLog(@"Resetting to authorised state");
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateData) withObject:nil];

    }else{

        NSLog(@"Resetting Twitter UI to non-authorized state.");

    profilePic.hidden = YES;
        profileName.hidden = YES;       

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use

```
[pool release];
```

rather than

```
[pool drain];
```

which is far more better practice.

Also can you try to release activityIndicator in the main thread?

From the code you have given I can't find any other cause for leak.. Have you tried to run your code using leak instrument and static analyzer?

Comment: Yeah I am running code using leak instrument. Please clarify me if there is any other alternative for fetching the image from an URL. I guess it is causing all the trouble.

Comment: Have you changed the activityIndicator thing that I mentioned in the answer? Also regarding fetching image from URL, your logic looks good and I don't think that is the cause of your problem

Comment: Yeah I have moved the activityIndicator to the main thread as you have suggested. Also in remaining two places apart from this program when I am fetching image from URL(running on main thread), even then there is a memory issue.

Comment: I m not sure, but have you look at user Sam's answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280053/iphone-memory-leak-nsdata-datawithcontentsofurl-uiwebview) question.. From what I understand there is no leak in the code you provided in the question, unless there is an apple bug in any of the methods you used.

Comment: I tried with all the possibilities from that solution. Eventually even that didn't work out. Still showing the leaks at NSData while using that solution.

Comment: I have run Build and Analyse tool. Yet no magic :( May be a leak with that method itself. However leak is 16bytes(using 5 times in app sums up to 80bytes), Can I ignore it and submit to the app store.

Comment: From the code you posted, I can't find any leaks.. One thing you can do is to go through all classes/interfaces in your project you have and make sure you are releasing whatever you are retaining (mainly properties I mean) in the dealloc.

Comment: The reported leaks are from NSURLConnection. I have submitted the app with those leaks and it is approved at the app store. Thanks for your help.