# Cocoa App using much more Memory than it should

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I'm developing an App that downloads and parses around 40k json files from an API.  Due to the structure of my program, i don't parse them immediately, but save them in an NSMutable array. Each json is around 1KB, most of them even less. If my calculation is correct, that should produce around 40MB (+ some overhead) of allocated memory. But when i run the App, the memory usage climbs up to over 4GB.

Am i leaking something here? Since i use garbage collection, i should not need to dealloc anything, right? Or is my calculation simply wrong?

Here my code:

```
- (void) loadItemsForIds:(NSArray*)idList {

    for (NSNumber* n in idList) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://someapi.com/somejson.json?id=%@", n]];
        NSData* response = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        NSDictionary *loadedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:nil];

        @synchronized(self.updateData) {
            [self.updateData addObject:loadedData];
        }

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(progressLoadingInterface:) withObject:[loadedData valueForKey:@"name"] waitUntilDone:NO];
    };

}
```

Edit:

Found out that the problem even exists, if i don't save the data into the array. After some research i stumbled upon this question which deals with the same problem: [iPhone - Memory Leak - NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl & UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280053/iphone-memory-leak-nsdata-datawithcontentsofurl-uiwebview)

My question might need to be deleted then.

Comment: garbage collection? or just arc

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - Memory Leak - NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl & UIWebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280053/iphone-memory-leak-nsdata-datawithcontentsofurl-uiwebview)

Answer (score 0):

`[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:nil]` parses the JSON data into objects. This will take up more memory than the 1K of JSON data.

In addition, `NSString` is likely storing all your string data as `unichar`, which is a 16-bit representation: double the size of the UTF-8 encoding assumed in the JSON data.

Depending on the contents of the JSON, I can believe that 1K of JSON data could become 10K of objects.

---

But this is all guess work. Use Instruments (Product > Profile) to check memory usage. That will give you a better idea what objects are taking up all the memory.

Comment: When profiling with Instruments, all seems to be fine, with a Persistent Bytes of 37MB after 3000 json objects which is fine. But as soon as i try it without using Instruments, the memory usage is a lot higher (around 181MB after 3000 objects) I don't understand whats going on here

Answer (score 0):

you never release memory between the 40k iterations.
=> You never give anybody the chance to do so either (arc/gc)

wrap the loop **body** in an `@autoreleasepool {...}` so memory is drained

```
for (NSNumber* n in idList) {
    @autoreleasepool {
         NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://someapi.com/somejson.json?id=%@", n]];
        NSData* response = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        NSDictionary *loadedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:nil];

        @synchronized(self.updateData) {
            [self.updateData addObject:loadedData];
        }

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(progressLoadingInterface:) withObject:[loadedData valueForKey:@"name"] waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't do the trick.. Also: i thought ARC auto releases memory allocated inside a loop at the end of it?

Comment: yes but without the pool, memory would go all the way up and only be released after all iterations

Comment: then your objects are that big indeed :D profile how big the objects are